# Design optimization method using indices

Tags: robotic-arm, kinematics, manipulator, optimization

There are several methods like manipulability and conditioning index for design optimization kinematics performance, but these methods rely on the singular values of the jacobian matrix. I described kinematics by screw theory using dual quaternion that is singularity-free. I need an index to optimize links length and think, I shouldn't use manipulability and conditioning index for my purpose. What do you think???

Comment: The root of this question seems to be a duplicate of https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/20779/dexterity-calculation-with-dual-quaternions.  Did that post not clear up your question about calculating manipulability with a dual quaternion based Jacobian?

Comment: @Ben i think when we used  singularity-free methods , we have infinite solutions at robot's singularity configuration and algorithm will give one solution. it's referred to property of quaternion, now what i dont understand it's end-effector motion. do end-effector becomes blocked in certain directions at singularity configuration?

Comment: That sounds like a completely different question.  Please start a new question thread for that.

Comment: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1608527/gimbal-lock-easier-to-control-with-quaternions) it's what i understand @Ben

Comment: Does it really make sense to optimize kinematics without regard to dynamics?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is likely that you are confusing two uses of the word “singular”:

1. The singular values of a matrix as found via singular value decomposition.
2. The singular configurations (or singularities) that occur when the Jacobian loses rank.

Comment: I agree that the OP is likely confusing these terms.  But can you elaborate on your answer and provide some detail?

Comment: I don't think there's really much to add. The question is "how do I analyze something's singular values if it doesn't have a singularity? And the answer is "you're confusing two different meanings of the word singular." Your comment handles the answer to what would be a followup question; feel free to add it here or make a second answer.

Comment: @RLH you know SVD and singularity are considered together. i used screw theory using dual quaternion so i think it's not necessary using SVD to investigate singularity. but can i  apply SVD in order to optimize links length?is it right?